# paddihng、marginなどの変数を1ずつ上げていきたい時に下記のようにxを付けるしか方法が思いつかないのですが、どのように対処していますか？

Tags: css, postcss

paddihng、marginなどの変数を1ずつ上げていきたい時、下記のようにxを付けるしか方法が思いつかないのですが、どのように対処していますか？

1ずつ上げるまでは行わずにだいたいだけ作って
そこに当てはまらなければ、変数での指定はしないのが一般的なのでしょうか？

```
/* margin */
--margin-small: 2rem;
--margin-medium: 4rem;
--margin-large: 6rem;
--margin-large-x: 7rem;
--margin-large-xx: 8rem;
--margin-large-xxx: 9rem;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

例示のように1remずつ差をつけて使い分けることがあまりありません。
実際に例示されたように使用するのであれば、smallやmediumなどのような表現ではなくどの変数がどの値なのかわかるように命名したほうが良いのではないかと思います。

```
--margin-2r: 2rem; // --margin-2remの意
--margin-4r: 4rem;
--margin-5r: 5rem;
```

Comment: `2rem` という値を持つ `margin-2r` という変数には意味がありますか？ `2rem` と直接書くのと変わらないように思います。

Comment: --margin-small: 2rem;
--margin-medium: 4rem;
--margin-large: 6rem;のみにして他の細かい数値はこのようにするという事でしょうか？

Comment: @mjy 主旨としては大量にclassを作成するのであれば抽象的な言葉よりも具体的に置いたほうが良いと言う部分なので`2rem`と書いた場合でも意味は変わりません。紛らわしくてすみません。

Comment: @nicomesecond 例として数個だけ取り上げました。smallやmediumなどの抽象的な言葉ではなく、必要な数値を表現できる変数名にすれば良いと思います。

Comment: 抽象的にあえてしているのは、その後グロース八ックなどで隙間を変更した際にhtmlをいじらなくても一括変更するためです